# For loop exits while downloading outlook email attachments python

Tags: python, loops, email, outlook

I have developed a code to iterate over outlook folder and download attachment from emails that have a predefined subject line and delete the message and delete messages that have a different subject than the predefined one.the code is as below

```
folder = inbox.Folders("folder")
for msg in folder.Items:
    if msg.Subject == "Predefined msg Subject":
        for att in msg.Attachments:
            msg_date = msg.SentOn.srftime(%Y-%m-%d)
            att.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(dest_folder, msg_date + "_" + att.Filename)
    else:
        pass
    msg.Delete()
    continue
```

I have about 150 messages in the folder, there are about 8 messages with required attachments and others are just to bedeleted. but the loop above breaks at 73 exactly (i used a counter and msg.Subject to where it breaks and why). The sencond run then breaks after ~24 and so forth. I had to run the code 3 more times to go over all the emails from folder. Any idea why the code exits loop

Comment: on another note, why do you `continue` at the end of the loop?

Comment: And you don't need `else: pass`

Comment: Does your code exit gracefully or does it break? If it is later, try adding `try-except` block and log the exception / stack trace.

Comment: thanks Greg and meow.. for such a quick reply, I did not have w/o continue and else:pass at the beginning but added when the code exited after 75 msgs

Comment: I believe that `msg.Delete()` may shrink `folder.Items` so that you end up skipping items in your iteration.  Instead of deleting them try adding them to a list of `msgs_to_delete` (as in `msgs_to_delete.append(msg)`) and then when you are done with your loop do `for msg in msgs_to_delete: msg.Delete()`  of course you'll need to create `msgs_to_delete = []` before your first loop.

Comment: Heisenberg.. it does gracefully no error msg ., try except did not help
Steven -- delete the msg is a requirement due to outlook size. We can not keep old msgs esp with 2M attachments

Comment: @Swadesh : Then it must be because your loop has no items to iterate because you are modifying the folder while iterating over it. Try a for loop with a `range` instead.

Comment: @Swadesh.  I'm not saying not to delete them.  I'm saying don't delete them *inside* the loop.  Or try to do `for msg in list(folder.Items):` which may solve the problem because `msg.Delete()` would have no side effect on a Python `list` but probably has a side effect on an Outlook `folder.Items`.  Note that I enclosed `folder.Items` in `list()`.

Comment: Excellent suggestions @Steven and heisenberg.. will try rightaway. It makes sense as it stops around halfway i.e at 76th msg out of 150 and 38th out of remaining 75

Comment: @Heisenberg: If the container is shrinking a for-loop with range would not solve the problem.  Eventually the index would be out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is modifying the collection it is iterating over. Instead of using a "for" loop use a loop from items.Count down to 1.

As a side note, iterating through all messages in a folder is a horrible idea - use `Items.Restrict` or `Items.Find/FindNext` to let the message store find the matches for you.

Comment: Great work guys.. I did Items.Restrict the list to go through (however "or" for two conditions on the restrict did not work, I will research further on this) and Items.FindNext to find the next item. This did the trick.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as the answer.